# JQ with nested JSON

Tags: json, key, jq

Hello I am new to JQ and command line tools in general so I am really lost with this. I have a JSON file in the form of:

```
{
    "Z": {
        "00": [{
                "e": "A000"
            }, {
                "e": "A020"
            }
        ],
        "01": [{
                "e": "A102"
            }, {
                "e": "C027"
            }
        ]
    },
    "X": {
        "00": [{
                "e": "P002"
            }, {
                "e": "T027"
            }
        ],
        "01": [{
                "e": "A003"
            }, {
                "e": "A020"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

where each object is a seven character alphanumeric code.

What I am looking for is a command to output each code separated by a newline so like this:

```
Z00A000
Z00A020
Z01A102
Z01C027
X00P002
X00T027
X01A003
X01A020
```

The format of the JSON will always be the same though the names "Z" and "X" and the sub names "00" "01" etc are liable to change so they cannot be hard coded.

As already stated I am new to this and the closest I have come is

```
jq '.[] | .[] | .[] | .e'
```

which gave me a list of the the last four characters of the codes.

To be honest I am completely lost so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that is based on the uniformity of the format.

First, let's define a helper function that handles JSON objects whose values are arrays of objects of the form `{"e": _}`:

```
def combine:
  keys_unsorted[] as $k
  | $k + (.[$k][]|.e) ;
```

Now the solution can be written in just two lines:

```
keys_unsorted[] as $k
| $k + (.[$k]|combine)
```

Using the -r command-line option will cause the strings to be emitted without enclosing quotation marks.

### Another strategy

The following is not only much more general but also illustrates a different strategy that opens up further generalizations and variants:

```
paths as $p
| getpath($p) as $v
| select($v | type == "string")
| $p
| map(select(type=="string"))
| map(select(. != "e"))
| . + [$v]
| join("")
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for the answer. I'm going to have to do a bit of reading to get my head around what the code actually does. It definitely works though.

Comment: Hi, just to let you know that when I ran your code on the large json file I have (~192000 objects) the first two pieces of code listed over 2 million objects instead of 192000. The third strategy gave the correct result. I was piping (if that is the correct term i.e. using >) to a text file so I don't know if that has any bearing on why the first two failed. I tested on both Linux and Windows and both gave similar results. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I had a look and the format seems the same. The only difference is that in my OP example under Z and X there are two sub objects (probably wrong terminology) "00" and "01" whereas in the large file there may be any number ( > 0 ) of sub objects . They are all arrays in which all items are {"e":_} objects though. I can upload the file somewhere if you want to test it yourself.

Comment: Yes, by all means upload it.  You could also try using a schema-inference tool, such as the one at https://gist.github.com/pkoppstein/a5abb4ebef3b0f72a6ed (disclaimer: I wrote it :-)

Comment: [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bd3yp6bNTmgYNtDf7kGQUHOMuXUApcX5/view?usp=sharing  Being honest I have no idea how to use the schema-inference tool you linked to.

Comment: You're right: the first solution had a bug in it; it has been corrected.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks again for your time and effort. You have been most helpful.